# Calling Tab Navigator inside a component screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am following react-navigation v3. As per the rules all the routes/screen should be passed through createAppContainer. Is there any way that some screen A can contain createMaterialTopNavigator inside it as child with two screens B and C and that screen A can be passed into App.js's createAppContainer??

Answer (score 0):

The app needs a single `createAppContainer` and you can use navigators as screens.
For example:

```
 const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
       Stack1: {
           screen: Stack1,
       },
       Stack2: {
           screen: Stack2,
       },
       Stack3: {
           screen: Stack3
       }
    })

const authenticationSwitch = createSwitchNavigator({
   LoginScreen: {
       screen: LoginScreen,
   },
   LoadingScreen: {
       screen: LoadingScreen,
   },
   BottomTabNavigator: {
       screen: BottomTabNavigator
   }
})


export default createAppContainer(authenticationStack)
```

EDIT.

Sorry and yes, i didn't understand your question.

To have such a behaviour, you can create a StackNavigator with your `customHeader` and from that have a child that is a `createMaterialTopNavigator.

This will work if the header is static out of the box, but if you need to have nested childs inside the topNavigator you have to dinamically change the header based off the current navigation state

Comment: Maybe you didn't got my question. Like in v2, we were able to define a custom header component and then below that a tab navigation with two screens inside the header component (making header as parent component and tabs as child navigator), I want to achieve such kind of thing in v3. Is that possible?

Comment: i edited my answer, see if this helps you or if you need some clarification

Comment: Can you help me with this another question of mine? Thing that you are explaining, you might understand from that question properly that I need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134398/passing-props-to-tabnavigators-screens